# Executing a Function on all Columns in a Select Query

Tags: sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I have defined this function, to trim trailing whitespace:

```
create or replace function trim_trailing_whitespace(value text) returns text as $$ begin return regexp_replace(value, '\s+$', ''); end; $$ language plpgsql immutable;
```

It works correctly when used in queries like this one:

```
select trim_trailing_whitespace(SomeColumn), count(*) from MyTable group by SomeColumn;
```

However, it fails when I try to utilize it with a wildcard, like so:

```
select trim_trailing_whitespace(*) from MyTable;
```

> LINE 1: select trim_trailing_whitespace(*) from MyTable;
>
> HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

How can I execute a function on all columns within a select query? In my case, I want to trim the trailing whitespace off of each column when performing the selection.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, define a second `VARIADIC` version of your function.  Iterate the args with a `FOREACH` and execute your current function on each argument.

Good example here: https://www.depesz.com/2008/07/31/waiting-for-84-variadic-functions/

Comment: or use row_to_json to pass the data in as json... keep in mind that unless your function returns a specific type of row, json may very well be one of the best options, considering on how it's being used.

Comment: This seems promising, but I was unable to get it to work on rows with multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic sql or expand `*` yourself manually.

```
SELECT FORMAT(
  'SELECT %s FROM %I.%I.%I;',
  string_agg(
    FORMAT(
      'trim_trailing_whitespace(%I)',
      column_name
    ),
    ', '
  )
  , table_catalog, table_schema, table_name
)
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_catalog = current_catalog
  AND table_schema = current_schema
  AND table_name = 'MyTable'
GROUP BY table_catalog, table_schema, table_name;
```

Comment: This simply returns nothing when I run it.

Comment: Did you replace `MyTable` with your table name?

Comment: I did. Still got no results. To be clear, I would like to apply this function to every column in every row, before returning them.

Comment: It returns nothing, as in no rows or columns. There are no errors.

Comment: It returns the SQL you need. you have to run that SQL. `\gset foo`; `\gexec foo` if you're using psql